# hugin crashes on 12.04

Tags: xorg

Hugin (panorama stitcher): Any help?

```
===> hugin
/usr/share/hugin/data/plugins/woa.py
   CAT:Control Points
   NAM:Warped Overlap Analysis
   fails @api-max
/usr/share/hugin/data/plugins/top_five.py
   CAT:Control Points
   NAM:keep 5 CPs per image pair
   fails @api-max
/usr/share/hugin/data/plugins/crop_cp.py
   CAT:Control Points
   NAM:Crop Control Points
   fails @api-max
/usr/share/hugin/data/plugins/shooting_pattern.py
   CAT:initial distribution
   NAM:6-1-1 Shooting Pattern
   fails @api-max
The program 'hugin' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 1148 error_code 1 request_code 154 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

Linux e520 3.2.0-30-generic-pae #47-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 18:52:06 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
guettli@e520:~


Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-30-generic-pae i686)
```

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ATI card, you can try to deinstall the `fglrx` package and install the `fglrx-update` package.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. The package fglrx-update was already installed and I **removed** it. Now I can run hugin and AngryBirds (via wine) again.

Comment: Related ticket on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/hugin/+bug/993923

Answer (score 0):

With or without fglrx-update I had several errors. Not only hugin, other apps, too. I installed Ubuntu 13.04, and the problems are gone. The root of the problem is still unknown, but I don't care any more.